# how to get skeltrack up and running in ubuntu 11.10 amd64

Tags: 64-bit, kinect

i saw an interesting post on [iloveubuntu.net](http://www.iloveubuntu.net/meet-skeltrack-free-and-open-source-kinect-gnome-technology) called [skeltrack](http://www.joaquimrocha.com/2012/04/03/controlling-gnome-3-with-your-hands/) free and open source kinect
my question is can i get it up and running on my laptop with web-cam using
 
Ubuntu 11.10 amd64 or do you need kinect hardware :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project states that it uses depth images ; a standard webcam cannot supply this information, so you would need the Kinect hardware to make it work.